# Recommended approach to documenting S4 classes in R package

Tags: r, documentation, r-package, r-s4, roxygen2

Following the example from *R packages by Hadley Wickham and Jenny Bryan.* I'm looking at suggested approach to generating documentation using `roxygen2` for `S4` objects. The example, which is available in [section 10.7.2](https://r-pkgs.org/man.html#man-s4), reads:

> Document S4 classes by adding a roxygen block before `setClass()`. Use
> `@slot` to document the slots of the class in the same way you use
> `@param` to describe the parameters of a function. Here’s a simple
> example:
>
> ```
> #' An S4 class to represent a bank account.
> #'
> #' @slot balance A length-one numeric vector
> Account <- setClass("Account",
>   slots = list(balance = "numeric")
> )
> ```

## Results

If followed this generates two documentation files with identical content. Formally speaking, there is the `Account` object and `Account` class described in `Account-class`.

[image]

## Considerations

It makes sense to have the `Account` object as it can be easily to used to create new instances of that class. However, I find that having one documentation entry only available as `Account-class` would be sufficient.

### Solution attempts

Adding `#' @rdname Account-class` or `#' @name Account-class` to `Account-class` still results in two documentation entry being generated.

## Questions

1. Is there a practical reason why the one may need two identical documentation entries one `Classname` and another `Classname-class` with identical content?
2. What's a good approach to document S4 classes using `roxygen2` with files named `Classname-class.R` and also creating objects `Classname <- setClass()`? In the desired scenario the following would happen:

   - New class is defined `Newclass-class.R` file
   - The class definition is of format `Newclass <- setClass("Newclass", ...`
   - the `roxygen` tags available in that file result in only one documentation entry: `Newclass-class` being created